# How do I handle LoginStatus control click?

Tags: asp.net

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 with a `LoginStatus` control in a Master page. When the status is `Login` and I click the link, the current page is attempted to be reloaded. I can see that `IsPostBack=True`.

If I use `Set Next Statement` to avoid my code in `Page.Load` the redirect to `Login.aspx` goes without a hitch, otherwise the current page tries to reload and for some reason it fails.

From `Page.Load`, what is the best way to detect that `LoginStatus` has been clicked? A click event handler won't work since it fires too late. `IsPostBack` won't work either (on its own). I do have a BaseMasterPage class that is inherited by my Master page, but again, the Master page loads after Page.Load in all of my pages.

Do I have to handle this click in every one of the pages that use this Master page?

Btw, I also have a `BasePage` class that all of my pages inherit. I'm just not sure how to detect that `LoginStatus` has been clicked - and if it has, how to handle it. Would I force a Redirect? That seems like overkill...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was being caused by an `<img src=` that did not exist on a remote server. This was causing my page to load twice. The first time through, `IsPostBack` would be `True`. The second time through it was `False`.

This is why I was unable to figure out why the redirect wasn't happening on its own. I'm marking this question as answered even though I should probably just delete the whole question. :S